# Managing video start/stop

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am doing an animation in which i use a video(I am using react-native-video). There is a bunch of animations going on and in certain point i would like to play video. So far, I did set up setTimout method in render()  like this: "setTimeout(() => {this.setState({paused: false})}, 5000)" and it works in the beginning but when i quit the animation to parent view then I keep receiving warnings about updating unmounted component. Is there another way of starting a video in a given time?

Cheers,
misi06

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to add `setState` in the render method. Add it in the `componentWillMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps` based on situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know i did it in wrong way, that's why i needed some guidance. It seems to resolve the issue!

Comment: Ok, so if you could not move the `setState` to the  `componentWillReceiveProps` provide the piece of your code with the video component.